# Syntax error in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to migrate a sql query into PostgreSQL. After running the query I get this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 20: ..._date is null or fcm.effect_end_date>=current_date()) limit ...
```

Below is my query:-

```
select farechart_master_id,farechart_name,version_number_service_stype,
fcm.route_id,st.service_type_name,fcm.passenger_type_id,
fcm.effect_start_date,fcm.effect_end_date,fcm.nignt_service,
fcm.peak_time,fcm.flexi_fare,r.route_number,r.route_direction,
r.effective_from,r.effective_till from farechart_master fcm 
left join rate_master rm on rm.rate_master_id=fcm.rate_master_id
left join route r on r.route_id=fcm.route_id 
left join service_type st on st.service_type_id=fcm.service_type_id 
where fcm.deleted_status=0 
and (fcm.effect_end_date is null or fcm.effect_end_date>=current_date())
limit 0 offset 10
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From which DBMS?

Answer (score 4):

`current_date` is a keyword. There are no parentheses after it.

```
fcm.effect_end_date >= current_date
```